# page html template is loaded before data in nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

This is a script tag of one of my website pages that I have used vue3 and nuxt3 to create that.

```html
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      posters: [],
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getPosters()
  },
  methods:{
    getPosters(){
      axios.get('https://something.com/posters/')
       .then(r=>{
              this.posters.push(r.data)
        })
        .catch(e=>{
        })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

but there is a problem and that is the data is loaded after the whole page loads; I have put the website in an online hosting service and I want to improve its SEO, but due the problem that the data is being loaded after the page template, google crawlers cannot read the data of the page so the google SEO rank of the page is not good now.

What can I do the solve this to get the data and show the template simultaneously together?

Comment: Do you have `ssr: true` in your nuxt config file? Also, why aren't you using `asyncData` or `fetch` lifecycle hook here? You're not supposed to make the call in `mounted`. I also recommend using `async/await`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kissu . But by the way how can I set ssr: true in nuxt.config.ts and then how can I deploy that? And how can I use fetch or asyncData without using mounted()?